# angular ui-bootstrap and leafletjs

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, leaflet

I want to do modal window for markers on map.
So, I include `leafletjs` for map and I want to include `ui-bootstrap` for modal window.

```
var scotchApp = angular.module('scotchApp', ['ngRoute', 'leaflet-directive']);
```

but if I do

```
var scotchApp = angular.module('scotchApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui-bootstrap', 'leaflet-directive']);
```

I get

```
[$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.6/$injector/modulerr?p0=scotchApp&p1=Error%…rjs.org%2F1.2.6%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3Dui-bootstrap%26p1%3DError%...<omitted>...6)
```

what's that? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are including a module that doesn't exist: `'ui-bootstrap'`

The correct version is with `'ui.bootstrap'`:

```
var scotchApp = angular.module('scotchApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'leaflet-directive']);
```

EDIT:

Don't forget to include the library in your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/uibootstrap.js"></script>
```

[Official UI-Bootstrap Getting Started docs here](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

Comment: What do you mean? Have you included the script in your page?

Comment: var scotchApp = angular.module('scotchApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'leaflet-directive']); give me the mistake. 

if i add something to ['ngRoute', 'leaflet-directive'], it gives the same mistake. so, I cannot understand, whats wrong.

Comment: You are using 'ui-bootstrap' which is wrong. The correct name of the mdoule is 'ui.bootstrap'

Comment: var scotchApp = angular.module('scotchApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'leaflet-directive']);
also gives [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.6/$injector/modulerr?p0=scotchApp&p1=Error%…rjs.org%2F1.2.6%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3Dui-bootstrap%26p1%3DError%...<omitted>...6)

Comment: Have you downloaded and included the script in your page?

Comment: I add <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js"></script>

Comment: Is this script added at the end of the page? Maybe it is added after you are trying to use it and when you include it the module is not loaded yet. Could you edit the question and add your html page?

Comment: <script src="/libs/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js"></script>
    <script src="/libs/angular-leaflet-directive.js"></script>

sorry, all html is quite difficult

Comment: In a previous comment of yours you said that using 'ui.bootstrap' throws error but the error that you pasted here is the same as when using 'ui-bootstrap'. Please check again since the error can't be the same.

Comment: i checked again. the same.